# C# HttpClient GetStringAsync Task returns early

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on an ASP.NET project and I am using a custom REST service we created to get JSON data for the site.  I am using the HTTPClient to invoke the REST service.  But when I call the ProcessRestMethod routine I created below, at times the task will return the right result but at times the task will not have finished executing and the routine will return.  What am I missing in async calls?  My ProcessRestMethod code is below. Thanks:

```
private string ProcessRestMethod(string methodName, string parameters)
{
    string result = "";
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string strParams = parameters;

        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)) && (parameters.IndexOf('?') != 0))
            strParams = "?" + parameters;


        var task = httpClient.GetStringAsync(baseUri + methodName + strParams);
        task.Wait();
        task.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            var tresult = t.Result;
            result = tresult;
        });
    }
    if (result == "")
        result = "{\"status\":{\"code\":1000,\"message\":\"Unkown Error Ocured\"}}";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this in such a complicated way, but in any case, you're never waiting for the continuation. Sometimes, it may run before you get to the `if (result == "")`, sometimes it will not.

Comment: Why aren't you using `async/await`? What you are doing now simply wastes *two* threads, instead of letting ASP.NET reuse the original thread while GetStringAsync executes

Comment: Moreover, if you care about *errors*, use `GetAsync` and check the status of the response. In the vast majority of cases, these are very well-known errors, eg wrong path, unauthorized etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It's unlikely that the code could correct itself if it code unauthorized, 404 etc. (configuration errors) Thus, getting a specific exception isn't going to help. Secondly, IIRC the HttpClient only have an async interface, thus one have to use the function. Using it doesn't imply that async/await is the best solution (if everything on top in the call tree is synchronous)

Comment: @jgauffin first, didn't say anything about exceptions. Second, 404 isn't a *configuration* error - it may mean the file isn't there *yet*. Or a 403 may mean that the wrong account was used. Or a 429 - too many requests etc. Ignoring these and returning an "Unknown error" is almost a bug. The comment about the interface isn't correct either - using HttpClient means you are *already* async. In any case, it's what's underneath that dictates whether `async` is a good choice. If the code on top isn't async, you can choose to mimick synchronous execution, or modify it to take advantage of async

Comment: My point was that none of those errors can typically NOT be handled at runtime. they require some sort of manual analysis first. Even 429 requires that. I do not *expect* 429 to happen when I call a web service. b) I do not understand your reasoning about everything being async just because HttpClient is being used. You are just guessing how the OPs code look like. From my POV he could just have picked it for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is get the Result property of the task - this will wait for it to finish and return the result.

What you were previously doing is starting a "continuation" task to get the result. This will cause the result to be obtained in a different thread, so you have the race condition you described.

```
  private string ProcessRestMethod(string methodName, string parameters)
  {
        string result = "";
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string strParams = parameters;

            if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)) && (parameters.IndexOf('?') != 0))
                strParams = "?" + parameters;


            var task = httpClient.GetStringAsync(baseUri + methodName + strParams);
            // Just call `task.Result` here :)
            result = task.Result;
        }
        if (result == "")
            result = "{\"status\":{\"code\":1000,\"message\":\"Unkown Error Ocured\"}}";
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yup. I tend to prefer `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` nowadays, though - it preserves the exception information much better.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to show OP how to rewrite the code using async/await rather than blocking on a Task and risking a deadlock. The code is an almost idiomatic example of [what not to do with Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @spender I tend to answer the question as asked. The problem with rewriting the method given to be async is he is immediately going to get a compile error from the calling code, as the method will return a Task, not a string. I agree he needs to learn how Tasks work better, but I'm not completely convinced an SO answer is necessarily the right place for it. Really, I should also teach him what a race condition is, which means teaching him what a thread is, which means teaching him what a process is, which means...(repeat ad nauseum)

Comment: You are re-declaring `result` inside the `using` block scope. This shouldn't compile.

Comment: Good spot, thanks - I missed that because it's masked by the compiler error for the missing `baseUri` variable, but that is from his code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using

> async/await

```
    private async Task<string> ProcessRestMethod(string methodName, string parameters)
    {
        string result = "";
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string strParams = parameters;

            if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)) && (parameters.IndexOf('?') != 0))
                strParams = "?" + parameters;


            result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(baseUri + methodName + strParams);

        }
        if (result == "")
            result = "{\"status\":{\"code\":1000,\"message\":\"Unkown Error Ocured\"}}";
        return result;
    }
```

You can read more about tasks, async and await here
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/c-async-what-is-it,-and-how-does-it-work/
http://www.dotnetperls.com/async
And Importantly this one explains the best
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: That won't compile: `The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>`

Comment: -1 incorrect syntax and you cannot just assume that the method can be made async, it depends on the type of application and the call tree.

Comment: @jgauffin actually you *can* assume the method can be made asynchronous if it contains at least one asynchronous call. Making it "synchronous" is what requires effort and can lead to complications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Not when Async methods are the only ones available in the class API. I'm glad that you've never seen any developers using APIs in a way that they are not intended. Assuming what the OPs code looks like is just speculations.

Comment: @jgauffin on the contrary, I've seen web farms melt because developers called `Wait()` instead of using `async`, not realizing that blocking actually starts with a SpinWait() before actually blocking the thread. As a result. CPU skyrocketed, items remained in the queue and eventually IIS recycles rippled across the farm during peak hours. What you call "synchronous" is actually faked. It's not the API's problem, it's a misunderstanding of what is involved in network calls, the behaviour of the thread pool etc. In the end, all I/O operations are asynchronous at the driver level

Comment: I know. You are still missing my point. You cannot assume what the OPs code look like (i.e. if it's async or not). thus an answer just giving an async solution is not really answering the question. An answer detailing why "sync" code is not a good solution and then giving an alternative would have been fine.

Comment: GetStringAsync already states that it is async, I do see your point but from my experience if you want to use GetStringAsync then use async/await.
There is a lot more going on with async/await which is why I gave links to examples and explanation.